# The memory space is allocated to the data members of a class only when an object is declared, then why Sizeof(class_name) is giving me result?

Tags: c++

Where will data member and method store if we don't declare the class object and compile it?Does it occupy actual memory?

Like suppose we don't declare like following:

`class Dog{ int x,y; }; int main() { cout<<sizeof(Dog);return 0; }`

Comment: Because [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) doesn't work the way you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

> The memory space is allocated to the data members of a class only when an object is declared, then why Sizeof(class_name) is giving me result?

Because [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) will:

> When applied to a class type, the result is the size of an object of that class plus any additional padding required to place such object in an array.

Whether any objects are instantiated has no effect on what `sizeof` returns.

---

> Where will data member and method store if we don't declare the class object and compile it?Does it occupy actual memory?

Non-static data members of a class do not occupy any memory if no objects of the class are instantiated. Static data members do.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the size of a class is constant. That means every instance of `Dog` will have the same size as every other instance of `Dog`. It's possible to use the `sizeof` operator on a type because, even if we don't have an instance of `Dog` who's size can be measured, you can still deduce the size an instance *will* have based on it's declaration alone.